# jQuery tabs fade in fade out

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to fade in and  fade out  tabs and this is the code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
        var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

        $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
        $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

        $(this).addClass('current');
        $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current').fadeIn('slow').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');

    })

})
```

But the problem is that the content is repeated when I press on another tab. That means the text is repeated in another tab and in the section.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">

    <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">Tab One</li>
        <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">Tab Two</li>
        <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3">Tab Three</li>
        <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-4">Tab Four</li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
    <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
     Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
    <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    </div>
    <div id="tab-4" class="tab-content">
    Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please post your HTML.

Comment: Is a plugin an option? do you know http://os.alfajango.com/easytabs ?

Comment: @user993553 i see him but i didn't like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would prefer using id as a selector and adding ids to each of the li. So, your code would be:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#tab-link').click(function(){
        var tab_li_id = $(this).attr('id');
        
        var temp = tab_li_id.split('-');
      
        var div_active = 'tab-div-'+temp[2]; //temp[0] contaings tab, temp[1] contains li and tab[2] contains the variabale 1,2,3,4 depending upon which li was clicked.
      
      
        $('.tab-content').fadeOut(2000); //div
        $('.tab-content').removeClass('current'); //div
        $('.tab-link').removeClass('current'); //li
      
        $('#'+div_active).addClass('current'); //div
        $('#'+div_active).fadeIn(2000); //div 
       $('#'+tab_li_id).addClass('current'); //li


    })

})
```

```html
    <ul class="tabs">
      
      <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1" id="tab-li-1">Tab One</li>
      <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2" id="tab-li-2">Tab Two</li>
      <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3" id="tab-li-3">Tab Three</li>
      <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-4" id="tab-li-4">Tab Four</li>

    </ul>

    <div id="tab-div-1" class="tab-content current">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet....
    </div>
    
    <div id="tab-div-2" class="tab-content">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet....
    </div>

    <div id="tab-div-3" class="tab-content">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet....
    </div>
    
    <div id="tab-div-4" class="tab-content">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet....
    </div>
```

p.s. Make sure that you are including the jquery.js file.